# Why doesn't centripetal acceleration: $(2 \pi r)^2/r $ include a time or period term?

Tags: acceleration, centripetal-force

$$a_c=\frac{v^2}{r}=\frac {{(2\pi r)}^2}{r}= 4\pi^2 r$$

$V=2 \pi \ r/T$ = distance / time = 1 revolution/time for 1 revolution (period).

But why is there no $T$ in the above formula? i.e. why is $V$ replaced with 
$V=2 \pi r$ and not  $V=2 \pi r/T$ ?

Comment: Because the wording says "13. D Centripetal acceleration is given by the equation ac = v2/r. Since the object covers a distance of 2πr in ***1 revolution each second***".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics. It arises from a misunderstanding of a teaching resource.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because this is the type of misunderstanding that this site is (at least in part) designed to help. It is somewhat a shame that it has been downvoted heavily as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple explanation for this confusion. It is called a typo, although it leads to a very teachable moment:

When you doubt the result in a textbook or a paper, the very first thing you should do is compare the units of both sides of the equation. The left hand side has units $L/T^2$ whereas the right side has units $L$ ($L$ is length, $T$ is time).

Dimensional analysis is the single most powerful tool at your disposal.